# Repeated replacing elements in the list

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I have a large list of the following form

```
{{1, 2} -> -1, {1, 1} -> 1, {1, 2} -> -1, {1, 6} -> 1}
```

and I want to combine all of the pairs `x->y` that share the same `x` value by adding up their `y` values. For the above example I want to have

```
{{1, 2} -> -2, {1, 1} -> 1, {1, 6} -> 1}
```

and I want to do it using patterns and `ReplaceRepeated` command. I tried the following code:

```
{{1, 2} -> -1, {1, 1} -> 1, {1, 2} -> -1, {1, 6} -> 1} //. 
  HoldPattern[{x_ -> y_, a___, x_ -> z_}] -> {x -> y + z, a}
```

Can anybody tell me why above code is not working and how can I do it using rules?

Comment: `//.` is not really intended for combinations like these. Try `Merge[]`: `Normal[Merge[{{1, 2} -> -1, {1, 1} -> 1, {1, 2} -> -1, {1, 6} -> 1}, Total]]`

Comment: Thanks @J.M.issomewhatokay. You answer is correct. However, I mostly want to learn about patterns and I wanna know how can extract such patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, there may (or may not) be preceding, intervening, and subsequent elements in the list that must handled using [`BlankNullSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html)

```
{{1, 2} -> -1, {1, 1} -> 1, {1, 2} -> -1, {1, 6} -> 1} //. {start___, 
   x_ -> y1_, middle___, x_ -> y2_, end___} :> {start, x -> y1 + y2, middle, end}

(* {{1, 2} -> -2, {1, 1} -> 1, {1, 6} -> 1} *)
```

Comment: Because it is only coincidental that the first element of your list is one of interest (i.e., matching LHS of rule). In general, any number of non-matching elements could be at the start.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy):

```
Normal @ GroupBy[
    {{1,2}->-1,{1,1}->1,{1,2}->-1,{1,6}->1},
    First -> Last,
    Total
]
```

> {{1, 2} -> -2, {1, 1} -> 1, {1, 6} -> 1}

Comment: Also: `Normal @ Merge[Total] @ list`

Answer (score 3):

You can use  `SparseArray` setting the system sub-option `"TreatRepeatedEntries"` to `Plus`:

```
SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Plus}];
sa = SparseArray[{{1, 2} -> -1, {1, 1} -> 1, {1, 2} -> -1, {1, 6} -> 1}];
SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> First}];

Thread[sa@"NonzeroPositions" -> sa@ "NonzeroValues"]
```

> {{1, 2} -> -2, {1, 1} -> 1, {1, 6} -> 1}